# Adding a new field to django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am totally new in Django and I'm trying to use django forms for the first time. I have searched for this but I still haven't exactly found the answer. Basically I have a view like this:

```
def pay(request):    
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # I have to calculate the checksum here
        myModel = form.save()
    else:
        print form.errors
else: # The request is GET  
    form = PaymentForm()
return render_to_response('payment/payment.html', {'form':form})
```

and I want add an additional field, checksum to the form from the inputs I got from the form So when the user submits the entries the checksum should be added and added to the form and the form should be sent to an external server. But I don't know how to do that (I have defined checksum in my Model). Could anyone help me on this?

My model looks like this:

```
class PaymentModel(models.Model):
alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed!')
secret_key = '6cd118b1432bf22942d93d784cd17084'
pid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, validators=[alphanumeric])
sid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, validators=[alphanumeric])
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
success_url = 'http://localhost:8000/success'
cancel_url = 'http://localhost:8000/cancel'
error_url = 'http://localhost:8000/error'
checksum = 0

def calc_checksum(self):
    checksumstr = "pid=%s&sid=%s&amount=%s&token=%s"% (self.pid, self.sid, self.amount, self.secret_key)
    m = md5(checksumstr)
    checksum = m.hexdigest() 
    return checksum

def __unicode__(self): #returns the unicode representation of the object
    return self.name
```

and my form looks like this:

```
class PaymentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentModel
```

Comment: You need to add this field to the `PaymentForm`...

Comment: You can update your question and add your form structure to it, not send it as a comment. Also it is better you post your `PaymentModel` since you use `ModelForm`

Comment: I edited the thread as you suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `commit=False` keyword argument to `form.save()`:

```
def pay(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Will not save it to the database
            myModel = form.save(commit=False)

            # keep your business logic out of the view and put it on the form or model
            # so it can be reused
            myModel.checksum = form.calculate_checksum()
            myModel.save()
        else:
            print form.errors
    else: # The request is GET  
        form = PaymentForm()

    return render_to_response('payment/payment.html', {'form':form})
```

[Django `form.save()` documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: Unfortunately it still hasn't worked. I added the model and the form. Would it be possible to see why?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your issue is. Are you wanting to store `checksum` in the database?

Comment: No I want to pack checksum along with the other data (pid, sid, amount, etc) and send them all to an external server that requires these fields.